# UINavigationController - detect when navigated back to root view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I'm trying to do this by using the delegate method

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
```

But how can I determine if `viewController` is the root view controller? It seems there is only a method for topViewController, which is not what I want.

Or is there a better way to determine when I have navigated back to the root of the nav controller by pressing the back button?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check if `viewController` is the same as the first view controller in the nav stack:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    UIViewController *root = navigationController.viewControllers[0];

    if (viewController == root) {
        // moving to the root controller
    }
}
```